# UVA problems 12503 gives TLE

Tags: c

I am trying to solve 12503 problem on UVA online judge. I think I have figured out the solution, but it gives me TLE. Here is the problem :

You have a robot standing on the origin of x axis. The robot will be given some instructions. 
Your task is to predict its position after executing all the instructions.

• LEFT: move one unit left (decrease p by 1, where p is the position of the robot before moving)

• RIGHT: move one unit right (increase p by 1)

• SAME AS i: perform the same action as in the i-th instruction. It is guaranteed that i is a positive

Input
integer not greater than the number of instructions before this.
The first line contains the number of test cases T (T <= 100). Each test case begins with an integer n (1 <= n <= 100), the number of instructions. Each of the following n lines contains an instruction.

Output

For each test case, print the final position of the robot. Note that after processing each test case, the
robot should be reset to the origin.

Sample Input

> 2
>
> 3
>
> LEFT
>
> RIGHT
>
> SAME AS 2
>
> 5
>
> LEFT
>
> SAME AS 1
>
> SAME AS 2
>
> SAME AS 1
>
> SAME AS 4
>
> Sample Output
>
> 1
>
> -5

Here is my code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char com[102][20];
int command(char comd[], int pos);

int main() {
    int t;
    int pos;
    int i, n;
    char tmp[20];

    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        int j;

        pos = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            gets(com[j]);
            if (strcmp(com[j], "LEFT") == 0)
                pos--;
            else if(strcmp(com[j], "RIGHT") == 0)
                pos++;
            else {
                pos = command(com[j], pos);
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n", pos);
    }

    return 0;
}

int command(char comd[], int pos) {
    if (strcmp(comd, "LEFT") == 0) {
        pos--;
        return pos;
    }
    else if (strcmp(comd, "RIGHT") == 0) {
        pos++;
        return pos;
    }
    else{
        int a = atoi(&comd[8]);

        return command(com[a-1], pos);
    }
}
```

Is there any suggestion why this code gives TLE ?

Comment: Doesn't the `scanf("%d",&n)` leave the newline in the buffer so that the first `gets(com[j])` will read a blank line?

Comment: It means i have to use fflush(stdin) ?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not standard. You're best to read line by line with `fgets` and use `sscanf` on the line. To fix your code as is, you could just put `while (getchar()!='\n') ;` right after `scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: So, it is the reason why my code gives TLE ? :D

Comment: Liberal use of spaces in your code makes it a lot easier to read.  I've given you some of mine, but I'm sure you can turn up some of your own if you look around a bit.  Check the top shelf in the cupboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the `int command(char comd[], int pos)` function, you are using recursive call at the last line. This may lead to TLE.

To solve this problem you can use another array to store the number of steps taken by the robot at a command. You just have to access the index of the array later to get step at a previous command.

Here is how I would do it-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int move[110];
int getMove(char inp[], int);

int main()
{
    int t, n;
    char inp[50];

    scanf(" %d ",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf(" %d ",&n);

        int i, pos = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            gets(inp);
            pos += getMove(inp, i);
        }

        printf("%d\n",pos);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getMove(char inp[], int i)
{
    if(inp[0]=='S')
    {
        int j;
        sscanf(strrchr(inp,' ')," %d",&j);
        move[i] = move[j - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        move[i] = (inp[0] == 'L') ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return move[i];
}
```